# Clear architecture principle in Angular (Bob Martin)?

Tags: angular, architecture

I'm trying to follow the  architecture Bob's uncle principle. The main concept is outer layes is depened from inner, but not otherwise.

So, my top layer is service that makes http request:

```
export class ApplicationService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private applicationAdapter: ApplicationAdapter) {}
     getDetails(id: string): Observable<ApplicationResponse> {
            return this.http.get<Application>(`${environment.apiUrl}/applications?id=${id}`).pipe(
                map((data: any) => {
                    return {
                        application: this.applicationAdapter.adapt(data.application)
                }),
            );
        }
}
```

Here I get response and put it to adapter `ApplicationAdapter`:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApplicationAdapter implements Adapter<Application> {
    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

    adapt(item: any): Application {
        return new Application(item, this.datePipe)
    }
}
```

The adapter returns specific model `Application`:

```
export class Application {
    constructor(
        public statename: string,
        public dt: Date
        public others properties...
        private datePipe: DatePipe,

         getFormattedData(): string {
             return this.datePipe.transform(this.dt);
         } 
}
```

As myt result model `class Application` depends on `private datePipe: DatePipe` I have to pass this dependency starting from `ApplicationAdapter`:

```
   constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}
   return new Application(item, this.datePipe);
```

Then the final model `Application` gets it to use inside method `getFormattedData(): string;`

So, I think it is architecture violation, because Adapter should not know about dependency `private datePipe: DatePipe`. And in this case my entity (**Application**) depends of internal dependencies, that violates the principle.

Could you explain me, how to solve this, maybe i'm wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use pipe in code, but not pass it as a dependency, you can add public static method to pipe. This method should contain transformation logic, and *transform* method should call your static method inside. So the pipe will look like:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'datePipe' })
export class DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  public static apply(date: Date): string {
    return date.toISOString();
  }
  
  transform(value: Date): string {
    return DatePipe.apply(value);
  }
}
```

And *getFormattedData* will be:

```
 getFormattedData(): string {
   return DatePipe.apply(this.dt);
 }
```